# Xamarin Cross platform development emuator unaccerelated

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've just installed Xamarin to start mobile development nevertheless looks like i have some emulator issues. See below the details.

This one i get when start project:

[image]

This what output shows:

```
You can continue with your emulator choice, but it will run slowly. For a better experience you should target a device or develop outside of a VM.

1>App4 -> C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\App4\App4\App4\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\App4.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: App4.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -no-accel -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started.
Runtime checks failed
```

Following some articles i enabled virtualization in bios which doesn't solve the issue as well as disabling hyper-v.

Comment: Are you developing from within a Virtual Machine?

Comment: `...you should target a device or develop outside of a VM...` Are you running Visual Studio within a virtual machine?

Comment: No i am not. It's regular Windows 10 (no VM)

Comment: did you install the intel accelerator and you also would need to disable Virtualization from BIOS

Comment: Install [Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager/HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows#Installing_Standalone_Intel_HAXM_on_Windows)

Comment: if you use Win10 1803 and VS2017 15.8, try the [Hyper-V platform](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a physical device (solves it for me all the time) or you can open the Android Device Manager, remove all the default devices, and start by adding the devices based on specifications.
For example, what I did in my case was
Open Android Device Manager from Visual Studio (you can use the quick launch)

[image: Open Android Device Manager]
[image: Android Device Manager]

Next is to spec up your device emulator to about 1 GB RAM

Make sure you have installed Intel HAXM and restarted your PC after disabling Hyper-V

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

Make sure to accept all prompt pop-ups.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe you could try using a physical device with USB Debugging enabled.

Comment: I solve the problem by disabbling in windows features Windows hypervisor platform. Unfortunetly i removed all devices as you suggested already. Is there anyoption to add default device again somehow without manuall adding it?

Comment: You will need to manually add the devices removed.

Recently, there is a Visual Studio Update that lets you run your Android Accelerated Emulators with Hyper-V On (If you use Hyper V)
Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.7.6